Laravel 8.x cannot save input text field value into db
I am trying to get user answers on a form. And after submitting the form, I can reach to all form values.
But some how, text field values are not recorded. They are recorded as NULL.
I tried with input array like
<input type="text" name="answer_1[]">
or like
<input type="text" name="answer_1_1">
result is the same.
At the beginning it was recording the values, but then nothing. Other form values are recording
enter image description here
I added $fillable and $guarded keys to model
protected $fillable = ['cevap'];
protected $guarded = [];
Form part
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <!-- Page title -->
                <div class="page-title">
                    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div
                            class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between justify-content-md-start mb-3 mb-md-0">
                            <!-- Page title + Go Back button -->
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                <h5 class="h4 d-inline-block font-weight-400 mb-0 text-white">Brain Storm Form</h5>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Additional info -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form id="form" class="mt-4" method="POST" action="{{ route('form.brainstormanswer.store') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="{{ $form->id }}">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="mb-0">Brain Storm Form</h4>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Title: {{ $form->title }}</h5>
                            <figure class="figure h-100" style="height: 180px">
                                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="{{ $form->s3File }}" class="img-center img-fluid" style="max-height: 400px">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Description</label>
                            <p>{{$form->content}}</p>
                            @if($form->s3File != null && $form->s3File != "")
                            <a href="{{ $form->s3Banner }}" target="_blank" ><i class="fas fa-file"></i> Click to open file</a>
                            @endif

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Due Date for Answer</label>
                                    <p>{{ $form->due_date_for_answer }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="form-control-label">Due Date for Score</label>
                                    <p>{{ $form->due_date_for_score }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Method: Reasons related to processes and methods.
</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                                    Answer
                               
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addrow('dvMethod',1)">
                                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Answer
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="dvMethod">
                            @forelse($answers->where('category_id',1) as $answer)
                                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="p{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->cevap}}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeExistingRow({{$answer->id}})"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row" >
                                 
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_1_1" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_1_2" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="category_count_1" id="category_count_1" value="3">
                            </div>
                            <!--second category-->
                            <div class="row">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Material:Reasons related to the materials used and resources.

</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                                    Answer
                               
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addrow('dvMetarial',2)">
                                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Answer
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="dvMetarial">
                                @forelse($answers->where('category_id',2) as $answer)
                                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="p{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->cevap}}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeExistingRow({{$answer->id}})"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_2_1" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="category_count_2" id="category_count_2" value="3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_2_2" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--third category-->
                            <div class="row">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Manpower:Reasons related to people (education, skills, motivation, etc.).


</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                                    Answer
                               
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addrow('dvManpower',3)">
                                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Answer
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="dvManpower">
                            @forelse($answers->where('category_id',3) as $answer)
                                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="p{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->cevap}}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeExistingRow({{$answer->id}})"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_3_1" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_3_2" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="category_count_3" id="category_count_3" value="3">
                            </div>
                            <!--forth category-->
                            <div class="row">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Machine:Reasons related to the machines used and technology.


</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                                    Answer
                               
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addrow('dvMachine',4)">
                                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Answer
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="dvMachine">
                            @forelse($answers->where('category_id',4) as $answer)
                                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="p{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->cevap}}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeExistingRow({{$answer->id}})"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_4_1" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_4_2" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="category_count_4" id="category_count_4" value="3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <!--sixth category-->
                            <div class="row">
                            <label class="form-control-label">Measurment:Reasons related to measurement and evaluation.



</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                                    Answer
                               
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addrow('dvMeasurment',6)">
                                       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Answer
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="dvMeasurment">
                            @forelse($answers->where('category_id',6) as $answer)
                                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="p{{$answer->id}}" value="{{$answer->cevap}}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeExistingRow({{$answer->id}})"  >
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                @empty

                                @endforelse
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_6_1" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 answer">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_6_2" value=""/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="category_count_6" id="category_count_6" value="3">
                            </div>

                            <hr class="mt-5 mb-4">
                            <!-- Buttons -->
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <label class="form-control-label d-none"><input type="checkbox" name="completed">Completed </label>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                               
                                <a href="{{ route('form.main.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('script')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('libs/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('libs/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            @if (count($errors) > 0)
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'There are fields blank or incorrectly sent',
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
            });
            @endif
            @if(Session::has('success'))
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Congratulations!',
                text: '{{ Session::get('success') }}',
                type: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
            });
            @endif
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .answer {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function addrow(id,category) {

            var count = $('#category_count_'+category).val();
            var html = '<div class="col-12 answer"><div class="row"><div class="col-10 col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="answer_'+category+'_'+count+'" value=""/></div><div class="col-2 col-md-2 "><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"  onclick="removeRow(this)" onclick="removeRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            $('#'+id).append(html);
            count++;
            $('#category_count_'+category).val(count);
        }

        function removeRow(btn) {
            $(btn).closest('.answer').remove();
        }
        function removeExistingRow(id){
             // Send an AJAX request to the Laravel route
                // Assuming you have included jQuery for simplicity in this example
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('ajax.delete_brainstorm_answer') }}",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { answer_id: id },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log('Data sent successfully');

                      $('#row'+id).remove();

                        //alert("Remove:"+response.remove_div + " Show:"+response.show_div);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.error('Error sending data:', error);
                    }
                });
        }

    </script>

@endsection



Controller part
public function store(Request $request)
    {
            // Log the request data
        Log::info($request->all());
        $request->validate([
            'form_id' => 'required|exists:App\Models\BrainStormForm,id'
        ]);
        $form_id = $request->form_id;
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $company_id=auth()->user()->company_id;
        

        for($j=1;$j<=6;$j++){
            $max=$request->input('category_count_'.$j);
         for($i=1;$i<$max;$i++){
            $answer_1=$request->input('answer_'.$j.'_'.$i);
            $ba = new BrainAnswer();
            $ba->form_id = $form_id;
            $ba->user_id = $user_id;
            $ba->company_id = $company_id;
            //$brainstorm_answer->answer =$answer_1;
            $ba->cevap =$answer_1;
            $ba->cevap2 =$answer_1;
            $ba->category_id = $j;
            
            $ba->save();
           // ddd($brainstorm_answer);
        }
         }
        

        //old answers
        $answers=BrainAnswer::whereFormId($form_id)->whereUserId($user_id)->get();
        foreach($answers as $answer){
            $brain=BrainAnswer::find($answer->id);
         
            $brain->cevap=$request->input('p'.$answer->id);
            $brain->cevap2=$request->input('p'.$answer->id);
            $brain->save();
        }


           if(isset($request->completed)){
            $form=BrainStormForm::find($form_id);
            $form->status=1;
            $form->save();
           }

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your answers have been successfully submitted.');
       
    }

**Model **
   <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BrainAnswer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'brain_answers';
   protected $fillable = ['cevap'];
   protected $guarded = [];
}

Form data (from laravel Log)
array (
  '_token' => 'g1JTcYP601ATpW7UYqsbhPGpkKiJlBKTVPjG7y6X',
  'form_id' => '6',
  'p7' => 'dsfsdfasd fsad fsadf',
  'p8' => 'sdfasdf asfd',
  'answer_1_1' => 'fsdfsadfadf',
  'answer_1_2' => 'sdfsdf s',
  'category_count_1' => '3',
  'answer_2_1' => 'erwer',
  'category_count_2' => '3',
  'answer_2_2' => 'werwf',
  'answer_3_1' => 'sdfwer',
  'answer_3_2' => 'sdfsdf',
  'category_count_3' => '3',
  'answer_4_1' => 'asdfsf',
  'answer_4_2' => 'sdfser',
  'category_count_4' => '3',
  'answer_5_1' => 'werwqer',
  'answer_5_2' => 'wqrwer',
  'category_count_5' => '3',
  'answer_6_1' => 'werwer',
  'answer_6_2' => 'qwerwer',
  'category_count_6' => '3',
)  


Please show the part of the view where category_count_X is placed

In your second loop before the ->save() method is called please add a dd($ba) which will show what values are getting saved. You're also creating your second loop as a string ($max) so its worth converting that to an int


@DevonRay it is showing excatly same data as in laravel log. Some how, when saving it value becomes NULL (It record the data to DB but that "cevap" field is NULL ). If I update the data it gets the value.

@BekirGüler I meant the context, not just the field, also to understand how it is valued and how it is returned. However, the suspicion is that $max=$request->input('category_count_'.$j); returns NULL and therefore in the loop $max is cast to 0 so the loop does not start.

it return number of answer input, normally I was using answer[] format but it didnt work also.  it is like if category_count_1   has 2 inputs it return 3  (I  have 6 categories).  I increase the number of input and it's value via javascript..... 'category_count_5' => '3',

@BekirGüler please share your model code

Hi, <?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class BrainAnswer extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'brain_answers';
protected $fillable = ['cevap'];
protected $guarded = [];
}

@BekirGüler you have to edit your question and add the complete Livewire class and the complete view, with the related javascript code otherwise we can't understand where the problem lies

Hi, I updated the content of my codes.

I see some problems with counters: for example if you delete a row in high position the field names will be misaligned with respect to the counter. Furthermore, when the lines are not filled they must be excluded from saving.
This is a possible solution, instead of counters we will use arrays and since I see that the scheme is repetitive, I suggest parameterizing the groups of questions and using loops.
The Controller
class YourControllew extends Controller
{
    // Let's create an array with parameters
    // In your example the category "5" is missing
    const ANSWERS_CATEGORIES = [

        ['catId' => 1, 'htmlId' => 'dvMethod', 'description' => 'Method: Reasons related to processes and methods.'],
        ['catId' => 2, 'htmlId' => 'dvMetarial', 'description' => 'Material: Reasons related to the materials used and resources.'],
        ['catId' => 3, 'htmlId' => 'dvManpower', 'description' => 'Manpower: Reasons related to people (education, skills, motivation, etc.).'],
        ['catId' => 4, 'htmlId' => 'dvMachine', 'description' => 'Machine: Reasons related to the machines used and technology.'],
        ['catId' => 6, 'htmlId' => 'dvMeasurment', 'description' => 'Measurment:Reasons related to measurement and evaluation.'],
    ];


    // This is an outline of the method that displays the page 
    public function index()
    {
        return view('your-view', ['answersCategories' => self::ANSWERS_CATEGORIES, /* other data goes here */]);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation must be managed, otherwise problems are caused when it fails (this is just an example)
        try {
            $validated = $request->validate([
                'form_id' => 'required|exists:App\Models\BrainStormForm,id'
            ]);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {

            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

        $form_id = $request->form_id;
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $company_id=auth()->user()->company_id;

        // New answers are grouped into a single bidimensional array
        foreach (self::ANSWERS_CATEGORIES as $aC) {

            foreach ($request->input('answer')[$aC['catId']] ?? []  as $answer) {

               // We only take the rows with a value
               if (!empty($answer))
               {
                  $ba = new BrainAnswer();
                  $ba->form_id = $form_id;
                  $ba->user_id = $user_id;
                  $ba->company_id = $company_id;
                  $ba->cevap = $answer;
                  $ba->cevap2 = $answer;
                  $ba->category_id = $aC['catId'];

                  $ba->save();
               }
            }
        }

        //old answers

        .....

The view
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

.....

<form .....>

    .....

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="form-control-label">Due Date for Answer</label>
            <p>{{ $form->due_date_for_answer}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="form-control-label">Due Date for Score</label>
            <p>{{ $form->due_date_for_score }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    @foreach ($answersCategories as $aC)

        <!-- {{ Number::ordinal($aC['catId']) }} category -->

        <div class="row">

            <label class="form-control-label">
                {{ $aC['description'] }}
            </label>

            <div class="col-9 col-md-9">
                Answer
            </div>

            <div class="col-3 col-md-3">

                <button type="button"
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        onclick="addrow('{{ $aC['htmlId'] }}', {{ $aC['catId'] }})"
                >
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add Answer
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="{{ $aC['htmlId'] }}">

            @forelse($answers->where('category_id', $aC['catId']) as $answer)

                <div class="col-12 answer" id="row{{$answer->id}}">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                   name="p{{ $answer->id }}"
                                   value="{{ $answer->cevap }}"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                                    onclick="removeExistingRow({{ $answer->id }})"
                            >
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            @empty
            @endforelse

            @for ($n = 0; $n < 2; $n++)

                <div class="col-12 answer">

                    <div class="row" >

                        <div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                   name="answer[{{ $aC['catId'] }}][]"
                                   value=""
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                                    onclick="removeRow(this)" 
                            >
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            @endfor

        </div>

    @endforeach

    <hr class="mt-5 mb-4">
    <!-- Buttons -->
     
    .....
@endsection

@section('script')

    .....
 
    <script>

        .....

        function addrow(id, category) {

           // there was one too many '<\div>' here 
           var html = `<div class="col-12 answer">

                            <div class="row"><div class="col-10 col-md-10">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                       name="answer[${category}][]"
                                       value=""
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2 col-md-2 ">
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                                        onclick="removeRow(this)"
                                >
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                       </div>`;

            $('#' + id).append(html);
        }
   
        .....
    
    </script>

@endsection


Firstly, I want to thank you very much. But It saved at first attempt but than samething happened it gets answers (cevap)  null. Something else going on here

I changed  values to static value, it is saving as null again.
if (!empty($answer))
{  $ba = new BrainAnswer();
$ba->form_id = $form_id;
$ba->user_id = $user_id;
$ba->company_id = $company_id;
$ba->cevap ="test";// $answer;
$ba->cevap2 ="test"; $answer;
$ba->category_id = $aC['catId'];
$ba->save();
}

You can add protected static $unguarded = true; in your model and remove $fillable and $guarded if you want to enable the update of all the columns in a cleaner way. Check in your model if you have mutators that alter the data before saving, check also if you have observers that manipulate the data. Keep in mind that the change I suggested in my answer concerns only the added rows: similar checks must be done for the rows read from the database

worked only once again. That is realy crazy
